# What does it mean when your function takes an argument containing | symbol?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm reading an article and came across a function that takes a symbol '|'. Can anyone explain what | does to the function argument?

For example:

```
handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) { ... }
```

The article can be found: https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a

Comment: It basically specifies the type of the argument. It can be either of type Error or of type HttpErrorResponse

Comment: This is a TypeScript type union: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: As previously stated, this is a type union implemented in typescript to handle multiple accepted types as arguments. Your function's argument can now be either an Error or an HttpErrorResponse.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain what | does to the function argument?

It is called a [union type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html).

`error: Error | HttpErrorResponse` means error can be of type `Error` OR `HttpErrorResponse`.